# What is location ID in Flipkart input payload?

Tags: flipkart-api

I was trying to upload a listing in my Flipkart sandbox account which requires a payload as an input.
I am not able to figure out what is my location ID or where will I get it from my flipkart dashboard.
This is my JSON payload :

```
{
    "<sku>": {
        "product_id": "<product-id>",
        "price": {
            "mrp": 0,
            "selling_price": 0,
            "currency": "INR"
        },
        "tax": {
            "hsn": "<harmonized-system-nomenclature>",
            "tax_code" : "<tax-code to determine goods>"
        },
        "listing_status": "ACTIVE|INACTIVE",
        "shipping_fees": {
            "local": 0,
            "zonal": 0,
            "national": 0,
            "currency": "INR"
        },
        "fulfillment_profile": "NON_FBF|FBF_LITE|FBF",
        "fulfillment": {
            "dispatch_sla": 1,
            "shipping_provider": "FLIPKART|SELLER|FLIPKART_SELLER",
            "procurement_type": "REGULAR|EXPRESS|INTERNATIONAL|MADE_TO_ORDER|DOMESTIC"
        },
        "packages": [
            {
                "name": "<package-identifier>",
                "dimensions": {
                    "length": 1,
                    "breadth": 1,
                    "height": 1
                },
                "weight": 1,
                "description": "",
                "handling": {
                    "fragile": true
                },
                "notional_value": {
                    "amount": 1,
                    "unit": "PERCENTAGE|<CURRENCY>"
                }
            }
        ],
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": "<location-id>",
                "status": "ENABLED|DISABLED",
                "inventory": 0
            }
        ],
        "address_label": {
            "manufacturer_details": [
                "<address_of_manufacturer>"
            ],
            "importer_details": [
                "<address_of_importer>"
            ],
            "packer_details": [
                "<address_of_packer>"
            ],
            "countries_of_origin": [
                "<iso_alpha2_code_of_country_of_origin>"
            ]
        },
        "dating_label": {
            "mfg_date": "<Manufacturing date of the product in linux EPOCH (Seconds)>",
            "shelf_life": "<Shelf life of the product in Seconds>"
        }
    }
}
```

This i what they need as the input. 
https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/listing-api-docs/LMAPIRef.html. You may use this Flipkart Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Location ID is a unique ID provided to every seller for it's registered and dispatch addresses. If you have created the Flipkart seller account and want to use Flipkart Seller APIs, you will be needing the location ID for which you will have to contact the Flipkart API team. They will provide you the location ID. You can mail the Flipkart support team for the same.